# Establishing entity groups while maintaining access to Long ids

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the appengine datastore, and all of my entities have Long ids as their PrimaryKey.  I use those ids to communicate with the client, since the full-fledged Keys take much more bandwidth to transmit.

Now, I want to form entity groups so that I can do complex operations within transactions, and it seems from http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html#Entity_Groups that I need to use Keys or String encoded keys - the simple Longs are not an option.

I don't mind refactoring a little to use Keys, but I still want to avoid sending the behemoth things over the wire.  How can I get a unique (per kind) Long identifier for an entity whose primary key is a Key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to use names (strings).  All of the [KeyBuilder](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory.Builder.html) methods that take names also have counterparts that take ids (longs).

For transmission, you simply need the name or id part of a [Key](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key.html).  Once you know the id or name, you can reconstruct the Key server side. If it is a child entity, you'll need to know both the parent and the child's names or ids.